# TextChanged doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, textchanged

I am trying to generate textboxes when the I press button add more so this is the code for onclick

```
protected void Add_TextBoxes(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index =  int.Parse(ViewState["pickindex"].ToString());
            TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();
            MyTextBox.ID = "tbautogenerated"+index.ToString();
            MyTextBox.Text = "tbautogenerated" + index.ToString();
            MyTextBox.Width= 250;
            MyTextBox.MaxLength = 128;
            MyTextBox.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            MyTextBox.CausesValidation = false;
            MyTextBox.AutoPostBack = true;
            MyTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyTextBox_TextChanged);
            picktexts.Controls.Add(MyTextBox);

        }

void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    }
```

but when I change in the textbox the textChanged doesn't work !!! what's wrong ?

HTML Code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="picktexts" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdress" runat="server" MaxLength="128" Width="250" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtAdress" Display="Dynamic" ID="rfvAddress" Text="* Required" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="bt_addtxtbox" runat="server" Text="Add more" OnClick="Add_TextBoxes"  CausesValidation="false" />
                    </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Add a break point to make sure its executing that part.

Comment: The new text boxes appear, but don't subscribe to the text changed event?

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work? Do you expect the event to fire as you type in the textbox? Because if so, it should only fire between posts by default.

Comment: @Kevin I think yes it doesn't subscribe

Comment: @Renan yes because I want to get the text

Comment: Is that because the updatepanel block the event ? try to add an trigger in updatepanel.  <asp:UpdatePanel>...<Triggers> <asp:PostBackTrigger event="xxx" /> </Triggers> </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Check the documentation for the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) event. It only fires between posts. You can force a post when the textbox loses focus by setting the [AutoPostBack property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx) to true. Otherwise, force a post after a character is typed. Happy coding.

Comment: For what it's worth, you did everything exactly correct for a WinForms application.

Comment: @Renan there is no lost focus event handler !!! and I already added AutoPostBack !!!

Comment: Viewstate messes up when you add a control dynamically. I use [ViewState["AddedControl"] = "true";](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Articles/ArticleTemplate.ASPX?ArticleID=2149). Second.. I don't know if it is required to set runat server property even when AutoPostBack is set but you haven't set runat property.

Answer (score 0):

I think the event handlers are getting *lost between posts*. the way ASP.NET works, every time you post a page back to itself, all objects are instantiated again, and their state is recovered from the ViewState. Normally a control that's declared in the aspx would reassociate itself with events by the declaration in its tag, which is not the case here.

So try associating the event handlers again during the page load. Like this:

```
void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in picktexts.Controls)
    {
        ((TextBox)c).TextChanged += new EventHandler(MyTextBox_TextChanged);
    }
}
```

And see if it works.

Comment: I double that HTML textchange is different. But kartal should at least see the post back event when focus changes.

Comment: I saw the post back event when focus changed but I can't get the textbox from picktexts it is null !!!

Comment: As Renan said, ViewState will be recreated on each post back. Can you refer to then link that I shared in my comment in your question (comment way down 10th)?

Comment: Your picktexts div very probably doesn't have a ViewState, or it isn't enabled. I'm rusty on this point. Do check Yogee's comment.

Comment: I didn't understand the ViewState part can you give me example ?

Comment: I really wish I could give you a simple answer. However, this is a lengthy subject, and as long as you don't understand the concept as a whole, you're going to have problems when coding like that. I recommend reading the [official overview documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448(v=vs.100).aspx). It's a long read, but once you grasp it, you'll be able to do more than you could before.